# Como enviar XML a un web service de la DIAN y retornar respuesta éxitosa

Tags: php, xml, webservice, postman

la verdad el tema de los web services lo conozco muy poco y con lo poco que se pues he intentado enviar un XML en este caso una factura electrónica para que el web service de la DIAN lo reciba y así me validé si el XML que les envié esta estructurado correctamente.

Bueno a lo que voy es que al enviar la factura electrónica en XML me devuelve un error que desconozco y seria de mucha ayuda si alguien que conoce del tema me explicara a que se debe, el error es el siguiente:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml-->    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
  <soap:Fault>
   <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
   <faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</faultstring>
   <detail />
  </soap:Fault>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Este es el código XML que estoy enviando:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml-->
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://www.aaa.com/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:crear_factura xmlns:ns1="http://www.aaa.com/">
        <nRegistros xsi:type="xsd:int">1</nRegistros>
        <aFacturas xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="tns:ItemsFacturas[1]">
            <itemFactura xsi:type="tns:ItemsFacturas">
                <sTipoOperacion xsi:type="xsd:string">10</sTipoOperacion>
                <sEmisorId xsi:type="xsd:string">900000000</sEmisorId>
                <sEmisorNom xsi:type="xsd:string">XXXXXX XXXX XXXX</sEmisorNom>
                <sEmisorRegimen xsi:type="xsd:string">48</sEmisorRegimen>
                <sEmisorPersona xsi:type="xsd:string">1</sEmisorPersona>
                <sEmisorMatricula xsi:type="xsd:string">123456</sEmisorMatricula>
                <sEmisorResponsabilidad xsi:type="xsd:string">O-07</sEmisorResponsabilidad>
                <sPrefijo xsi:type="xsd:string">01</sPrefijo>
                <sConsecutivo xsi:type="xsd:string">00000032</sConsecutivo>
                <sPrefijoRD xsi:type="xsd:string">SETT</sPrefijoRD>
                <dFecha xsi:type="xsd:date">2019-11-19</dFecha>
                <tHora xsi:type="xsd:time">11:44:32</tHora>
                <dVencimiento xsi:type="xsd:date">2019-11-18</dVencimiento>
                <sCurrency xsi:type="xsd:string">COP</sCurrency>
                <smetodoPago xsi:type="xsd:string">1</smetodoPago>
                <sformaPago xsi:type="xsd:string">2:Crédito ACH</sformaPago>
                <scondPago xsi:type="xsd:string">3: Fechafija</scondPago>
                <sAdquirienteId xsi:type="xsd:string">800062591</sAdquirienteId>
                <sIdDocIdentidificacion xsi:type="xsd:string">31</sIdDocIdentidificacion>
                <sAdquirienteNombre xsi:type="xsd:string">XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX</sAdquirienteNombre>
                <sAdquirienteRegimen xsi:type="xsd:string">48</sAdquirienteRegimen>
                <sAdquirientePersona xsi:type="xsd:string">1</sAdquirientePersona>
                <sAdquirienteMatricula xsi:type="xsd:string">457654</sAdquirienteMatricula>
                <sAdquirienteResponsabilidad xsi:type="xsd:string">O-07</sAdquirienteResponsabilidad>
                <sAdquirienteDireccion xsi:type="xsd:string">AV. 2N No. 31 - 97</sAdquirienteDireccion>
                <sAdquirienteCiudad xsi:type="xsd:string">Cali</sAdquirienteCiudad>
                <sAdquirienteMunicipio xsi:type="xsd:string">Cali</sAdquirienteMunicipio>
                <sAdquirienteDepartamento xsi:type="xsd:string">Valle del Cauca</sAdquirienteDepartamento>
                <sAdquirientePaisId xsi:type="xsd:string">CO</sAdquirientePaisId>
                <sAdquirienteEmails xsi:type="xsd:string">prueba@hotmail.com</sAdquirienteEmails>
                <nTotalFact xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</nTotalFact>
                <nSubTotalFact xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</nSubTotalFact>
                <nIvaFact xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</nIvaFact>
                <nRFTE xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</nRFTE>
                <nRICA xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</nRICA>
                <nRIVA xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</nRIVA>
                <nDescuentoFactura xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</nDescuentoFactura>
                <aDetalles xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="tns:ItemsDetalles[2]">
                    <item xsi:type="tns:ItemsDetalles">
                        <sPUC xsi:type="xsd:string">41054635</sPUC>
                        <sDescCat xsi:type="xsd:string">AAAAA AAAAAAA AAAA</sDescCat>
                        <sCodConcep xsi:type="xsd:string">108</sCodConcep>
                        <sTasaIva xsi:type="xsd:int">4</sTasaIva>
                        <sTasaIva2 xsi:type="xsd:int">0.00</sTasaIva2>
                        <sTasaRFTE xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</sTasaRFTE>
                        <sTasaRICA xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</sTasaRICA>
                        <sTasaRIVA xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</sTasaRIVA>
                        <nUnidadMedida xsi:type="xsd:string">94</nUnidadMedida>
                        <nDebitoFiscal xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</nDebitoFiscal>
                        <nCreditoFiscal xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</nCreditoFiscal>
                        <nCantidadVenta xsi:type="xsd:decimal">1</nCantidadVenta>
                        <nValorUnitarioFiscal xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</nValorUnitarioFiscal>
                        <nImpuestoFiscal xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</nImpuestoFiscal>
                        <nImpuestoFiscal2 xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</nImpuestoFiscal2>
                        <sDescripcionRegistro xsi:type="xsd:string">BBBB BBBBBB BBBBB</sDescripcionRegistro>
                        <sRFTE xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</sRFTE>
                        <sRICA xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</sRICA>
                        <sRIVA xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</sRIVA>
                    </item>
                    <item xsi:type="tns:ItemsDetalles">
                        <sPUC xsi:type="xsd:string">41054635</sPUC>
                        <sDescCat xsi:type="xsd:string">PPPPPP PPPPPP PPP</sDescCat>
                        <sCodConcep xsi:type="xsd:string">245</sCodConcep>
                        <sTasaIva xsi:type="xsd:int">0.00</sTasaIva>
                        <sTasaIva2 xsi:type="xsd:int">0.00</sTasaIva2>
                        <sTasaRFTE xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</sTasaRFTE>
                        <sTasaRICA xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</sTasaRICA>
                        <sTasaRIVA xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</sTasaRIVA>
                        <nUnidadMedida xsi:type="xsd:string">94</nUnidadMedida>
                        <nDebitoFiscal xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</nDebitoFiscal>
                        <nCreditoFiscal xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</nCreditoFiscal>
                        <nCantidadVenta xsi:type="xsd:decimal">1</nCantidadVenta>
                        <nValorUnitarioFiscal xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</nValorUnitarioFiscal>
                        <nImpuestoFiscal xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</nImpuestoFiscal>
                        <nImpuestoFiscal2 xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</nImpuestoFiscal2>
                        <sDescripcionRegistro xsi:type="xsd:string">VVVVV VVVVV VVVVVV</sDescripcionRegistro>
                        <sRFTE xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</sRFTE>
                        <sRICA xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</sRICA>
                        <sRIVA xsi:type="xsd:decimal">0.00</sRIVA>
                    </item>
                </aDetalles>
                <infoAdicional>
                    <campoadicional nombre="Idioma">es</campoadicional>
                </infoAdicional>
            </itemFactura>
        </aFacturas>
    </ns1:crear_factura>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Las pruebas las estoy haciendo en la aplicación de Postman, aunque también la he ejecutado en PHP, estoy utilizando cURL.

Este es el código de pruebas en PHP:

```
public function getXML() {
   # crea el string XML SOAP
}

public function sendToDian($wsUrl) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $wsUrl,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $this->getXML(),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
    CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "User-Agent: PHP",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Content-Length: " . strlen($this->getXML()),
        "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8",
        "SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/ValidarDoc",
    )));

    $res = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    $rq = curl_getinfo($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Por experiencia propia, te cuento que la mayoría de las fallas no son de nuestro lado sino de la DIAN, se metieron en una camisa de once varas ellos mismos porque su plataforma es de las peores que existen en Colombia. Trata de enviarla a otro destino, muchas veces el código funciona sin problemas.

Comment: estoy trabajando lo mismo para Guatemala. Tengo una duda, ¿cómo generas el string XML? Veo que tienes la siguiente función: public function getXML() { # crea el string XML SOAP } No estoy familiarizado, he logrado crear el XML en un archivo , pero al leerlo no puedo obtener el xml completo como un string para convertirlo a base64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la solución era un poco fácil y eso se debe a que me falto leer un poco más sobre esto, ya que el mismo web service te especifica como se debe mandar el XML. Por si alguien le sirve:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
   <Request xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <XmlContentBase64>string</XmlContentBase64>
    <fileName>string</fileName>
    <parentNit>string</parentNit>
   </Request>
  </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

Lo que me pedía el web service era en la etiqueta `<XmlContentBase64>` colocar el string XML en base64, el nombre del archivo `<fileName>` y el `<parenNit>` son opcionales.

Answer (score 3):

Buen dia, Si estas consumiendo el servicio web de la DIAN Colombia, el que adjuntas como ejemplo no es el request que actualmente usan para el envió de la factura. Te lo digo porque trabajo en una empresa que es Proveedor Tecnológico Autorizado y lidero el proyecto.

El web service que tiene la DIAN actualmente para factura electrónica es: 
https://vpfe-hab.dian.gov.co/WcfDianCustomerServices.svc?wsdl (Ambiente de pruebas o habilitación)

Y el request del mensaje SOAP es el siguiente:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wcf="http://wcf.dian.colombia">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <wcf:SendBillAsync>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <wcf:fileName>?</wcf:fileName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <wcf:contentFile>cid:1169004353780</wcf:contentFile>
      </wcf:SendBillAsync>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

El servicio SendBillAsync permite enviar una factura de forma asincrona. Es decir que no se recibe respuesta de validación inmediata y se puede enviar mas de un XML (Factura electrónica) en un ZIP.

Para que te orientes con el tema de Factura Electrónica en Colombia puedes buscar en la pagina oficial de la DIAN la documentación para el desarrollo.

https://factura-electronica.dian.gov.co/documentacion-normatividad-16.html

En la sección de anexos puedes decargar la caja de herramientas, esta contiene toda la información para hacer tu propio software de facturación electrónica.

Comment: Saludos me hechas una mano gracias. en facturacion electronica colombia DIAN